# Coloring output of a script that overwrites lines?

Tags: bash, stdout, overwrite, text-coloring

I'm using this to color the output of a script/command:

```
commandWithOutput | sed -r 's/(pattern)/'"${COLOR_RED}"'\1'"${COLOR_DEFAULT}"'/g'
```

(This will color all occurences of string "pattern" in the command's output.) And it works fine with traditional commands. However, if the script/command overwrites lines in its output (maybe this has more to do with a terminal/console than just standard output?), e.g.:

```
Building project X:
CXX Building file XYZ.cpp... [123/1034]
```

the behavior isn't as expected. My sed will still color the output but the overwriting doesn't work anymore, i.e.:

```
Building project X:
CXX Building file ABC.cpp... [1/1034]
CXX Building file DEF.cpp... [2/1034]
CXX Building file GHI.cpp... [3/1034]
CXX Building file JKL.cpp... [4/1034]
CXX Building file MNO.cpp... [5/1034]
// and so on...
CXX Building file XYZ.cpp... [123/1034]
```

Is there a way to color the output of a script/command that overwrites lines?

Comment: Please post the script/command that overwrites the lines. Enough example code so that others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I understand but in this particular case I don't even have access to its source code (it's a third-party tool) and also I would like my coloring command/script to work with any tool that overwrites lines in its output (if possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried several different ideas ... `IFS=$'\r'` + OP's `sed` command ... trying to use an intermediate pipe (`mkfifo`) for processing the output from `commandWithOutput` ... a few attempts at trying to unbuffer stdout and/or stdin ... but (so far) could only get a `awk` solution to work, so fwiw ...

**NOTE**: I'm assuming OP's command is generating a `\r` when overwriting a line; if this is not the case the OP can try piping their command's output to `| od -c` to see what character is at the 'end of the line', with the idea being to use said character in place of my `\r` references (below).

---

First we'll write a small script to generate some data, (re)printing over the first few lines, and then printing some 'standalone' lines:

```
$ cat overwrite
#!/usr/bin/bash

for (( i=1 ; i<="${1}" ; i++ ))
do
    printf "this is a test ... ${i}\r"
    sleep 1
done

printf "\nanother test output \t and a tab\n"

echo "X."
```

Running the above generates the following output:

```
$ overwrite 3
this is a test ... 3                      << this line is actually printed 3x times with suffixes of '1', '2' and '3'
another test output      and a tab
X.
```

[image]

Running this through `od` shows the `\r` at the end of the first 3 lines:

```
$ overwrite 3 | od -c
0000000   t   h   i   s       i   s       a       t   e   s   t       .
0000020   .   .       1  \r   t   h   i   s       i   s       a       t
0000040   e   s   t       .   .   .       2  \r   t   h   i   s       i
0000060   s       a       t   e   s   t       .   .   .       3  \r  \n
0000100   a   n   o   t   h   e   r       t   e   s   t       o   u   t
0000120   p   u   t      \t       a   n   d       a       t   a   b  \n
0000140   X   .  \n
0000143
```

---

We'll now look at one `awk` solution for recoloring a specific pattern in the output from our `overwrite` script ...

First we'll define the start and clear/reset variables for our desired color; for this exercise I'm going to use 'red':

```
$ myred=$(tput setaf 1)           # set our highlight color to red
$ myreset=$(tput sgr0)            # disable coloring
```

**NOTE**: There are a few ways to define these colors (and the disable/reset); I'll leave that up to the reader to pick what works best in their environment.

Here's one `awk` solution I found that works:

```
$ overwrite 3 | awk -v ptn="test" -v cstart="${myred}" -v creset="${myreset}" -v RS="[\n\r]" '{ sub(ptn,cstart ptn creset) ; printf $0 RT }'
```

Where:

- `-v ptn="test"` - we want to recolor all instances of the string `test`; we'll pass this in as `awk` variable `ptn`
- `-v cstart="${myred}"` - assign our highlight color code (red) to our `awk` variable `cstart`
- `-v creset="${myreset}"` - assign our color clear/reset code to the `awk` variable `creset`
- `-v RS="[\n\r]"` - redefine our input record separator as either `\r` or `\n`
- `sub(ptn,cstart ptn creset)` - replace all instances of `test` with `<red> + test + <reset>`
- `printf $0 RT` - print our new line; `RT` allows us to make use of the same `RS` that was used to parse out this record

Running the above generates:

```
this is a test ... 3                      << this line is actually printed 3x times with suffixes of '1', '2' and '3', and the 'test' string printed in red
another test output      and a tab        << the 'test' string is printed in red
X.
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like in my case the `commandWithOutput` doesn't use `\r` or anything similar. I'm even starting to suspect that it changes its behavior/output based on whether it's piped or not. Still, this is a great answer and works for `\r`-based commands so I'm accepting it.

Comment: yeah, I was afraid it wouldn't be **that** easy! :-)  likely some terminal/console level coding going on; I was running some tests with a script that changes/overwrites lines using `tput` ... and `od -c` is showing an assortment of hex/control codes, which in turn just starts to get really messy (if even doable) trying to reparse those codes (eg, via `awk`); thanks for the +pts anyway

Comment: In my case `od -c` only shows `\n` characters, nothing else, that's why I started to suspect my command's behavior differs when it's piped/redirected.